# Simple HTML data not displayed in extjs

Tags: extjs3, dataview

I have an XTemplate to display html data as shown below

```
var headerTmp = new Ext.XTemplate(
'<br><br><br>',
'<div class="contact-display-container" style="height:100px; width:400px">',
'<div style="font-size:12px; left:15px">Hello </div>',
'</div>',
'<br><br><br>'
);
```

I am referring the data in a dataview

```
var dataView1 = new Ext.DataView({
autoScroll: false,
tpl: headerTmp,
itemSelector: 'div.contact-display-container'
});
```

I am trying to display the data in a window

```
var win = new Ext.Window({
height:700,
width:700,
border:false,
modal:true,
title: 'Review Contact Information',
items:[{
    layout : 'vbox',
    items  : [dataView1]
}],
    buttons:[{
                text: 'Cancel',
                handler:function(){
                win.close();
                }
              }]
            });

win.show();
```

But the data "Hello" is not displayed on the window. Can you please tell me where am I going wrong.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

1. A dataview should be bound to an instance of a store. Try adding a store config to your dataview.
2. You are overnesting items in your window. You should add dataView directly as a child item to your window. If you need an extra parent level panel, either change it's layout to something like `fit` or if you want to keep it as a `vbox`, add a `flex` config to the dataview.

Here's a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/KUqM9/419/